# Setting up a for loop for an encryption scheme

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

As I [stated before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752881/for-loop-is-really-confusing-me) I am trying to make a specific `for` loop for an encryption machine (a toy machine, not one that is secure from the NSA).

When I press the encrypt button, I need the encryption to run and then produce the info encrypted in another text box. So I have a text box where the user enters the numbers to be encrypted (between 10000 and 99999) and then press encrypt and the info shows up in the second bar. I have the set up but the for loop is tricky.

These are my directions:

Add the necessary code to the “Encrypt” button to do the following:

a) Create a for loop to add 10 to the number entered on the first box and multiply the 
result by 3, add 20 to this result and then multiply it by 5, add 30 to this result and then 
multiply it by 7, etc. Follow that pattern 5 times (5 iterations).

b) After the iterations have been completed, there will be a resulting number in 
memory, let's say 75432179

c) Now, this number needs to be turned into characters (letters) by matching each digit 
to its corresponding letter of the alphabet based on the positions of the letters (0 will 
be matched with the 10th letter of the alphabet). For our example: the resulting letters 
will be: gedcbagi (g is the 7th letter of the alphabet, e is the 5th letter, d is the 4th 
letter, etc.)

d) The last step of the encryption process is to further scramble the letters by using the 
ancient Caesar's cipher: each letter replaced by another letter three positions to the 
right. Therefore, the final result in our example would be: jhgfedjl (Notice that you 
may also do steps c) and d) combined)

This is what I have so far for my script tags; please tell me what I'm doing wrong:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
    q=1
for (encryptThis=1; encryptThis <=5; encryptThis++){        
        if (encryptThis>=10000 && encryptThis<=99999){
        encryptinfo=((q+2)*10+encryptThis);
        }else{
        alert("number should be between 10000 and 99999");
        }}
    </script>
```

then for the bottom of my table by my inputs:

```
<tr>
    <td>Plaintext (Plain information)</td>
    <td><input type="text"  name= "encryptThis" size="16" onchange=' '/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value=" Encrypt " onclick='
        system.out.encryptinfo.print((q+2)*10+encryptThis);


       '/></td>
```

and....

```
<tr>
    <td>Ciphertext (Encrypted information)</td>
    <td><input type="text"  name= "encryptinfo" size="16" onchange=' '/></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You're lucky I saw this. When you're tagging a question, you should normally include a tag for the principal language that your question is about -- JavaScript in this case. That will direct the attention of people who know the language.  Your title should be more descriptive of the problem, not your state of mind.  And you should get your wonky shift key fixed (or use proper capitalization). A solid block of question text is hard to read. You should probably break it up into paragraphs too. Please be careful when asking questions.

Comment: system.out.encryptinfo is not a thing. Are you sure you aren't confusing Java and JavaScript?

Comment: Five iterations of a `for` loop would be done like this: `for (encryptThis=1; encryptThis <=5; encryptThis++)`.  Also, there is no `int` data type in javascript.  All variables are declared with `var`.

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00 ! do you have any idea what I should do for this loop? I don't know if I can make a function within this for loop or what because this specific situation has 5 iterations and they're all supposed to be increasing my value by different numbers

Comment: I do not understand the rest of what you are asking.  Folks can't help if they don't understand your question.  You can probably start by giving a more complete description of the encryption algorithm you're trying to implement.  Show all 5 steps in pseudo code (e.g. english words outlining each step) if you need to.

Comment: I'm trying to Create a for loop to add 10 to the number entered (encryptThis) and multiply the result by 3, add 20 to this result and then multiply it by 5, add 30 to this result and then multiply it by 7, etc. Follow that pattern 5 times (5 iterations). so encryptThis is the value (whatever is entered by the person writing in the text box that I've put in my html) and that what i need to be making a for loop for so i need to do

Comment: encryptThis+10*3 encryptThis+20*5 encryptThis+30*7 encryptThis+40*9 encryptThis+50*11

Comment: @jfriend00   (sorry i forgot to tag you)

Comment: b) After the iterations have been completed, there will be a resulting number in 
memory, let's say 75432179
c) Now, this number needs to be turned into characters (letters) by matching each digit 
to its corresponding letter of the alphabet based on the positions of the letters (0 will 
be matched with the 10th letter of the alphabet). For our example: the resulting letters 
will be: gedcbagi (g is the 7th letter of the alphabet, e is the 5th letter, d is the 4th 
letter, etc.)

Comment: d) The last step of the encryption process is to further scramble the letters by using the 
ancient Caesar's cipher: each letter replaced by another letter three positions to the 
right. Therefore, the final result in our example would be: jhgfedjl (Notice that you 
may also do steps c) and d) combined)

Comment: @user3479553 - it would be much better if you put this description into your question.  Use the "edit" link to update your question.

Comment: @jfriend00 okay i just did that

Comment: what is system.out ? it's not a DOM api,where does it come from? ditto for int q; it's definetly not javascript , are you mixing up javascript and java in jsp pages?

Comment: @jfriend00 no it is javascript and I know the q is wrong so i took it out. and I also took out the system.out cause I was confused by internet stuff this is what i have now:

Comment: q=1
for (encryptThis=1; encryptThis <=5; encryptThis++){     
  if (encryptThis>=10000 && encryptThis<=99999){
  encryptinfo=((q+2)*10+encryptThis);
  }else{
  alert("number should be between 10000 and 99999");
     }}
    </script>

Comment: @jfriend00 i posted it at the top in an edit and i kept the q because it's increasing by 2 and needs to start with 3. Again, I'm not sure that's right

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interpretation of what I think you're trying to do:

```
function encrypt(num) {
    var sum = 0, str, i, result, index;
    var chars = "abcdefghijklmnop";
    var charBase = "0".charCodeAt(0);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // ((2 * i) + 3) goes 3,5,7,9,11
        // ((i * 10) + 10) goes 10,20,30,40,50
        sum += (num * ((2 * i) + 3)) + ((i * 10) + 10);        
    }
    // convert num to string to get digits
    str = sum + "";
    result = "";
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        // get offset from "0" and add 3 for the cipher
        index = str.charCodeAt(i) - charBase + 3;
        // convert that index to a character
        result += chars.charAt(index);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It takes a number as an argument and it returns a string.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/UW245/

Comment: on the working demo I don't think I can use the addeventlister thats causing a problem because my math needs to be a little different so i had to change it and my chrome console is saying the addeventlister is an issue

Comment: @user3479553 - what working demo?  There's no `addEventListener()` in any of the code in your question.  I simply have no idea what you're talking about.  If you want help diagnosing a particular error, then you have to tell us EXACTLY what the error message is and exactly what line of code it's on and show us enough of that code for us to see what could be going on.  If you're talking about the `addEventListener()` in my demo, that's just to trigger the code to run in the demo - you can trigger the code however you want.