# How do I put a for loop encryption code into a workable table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, encryption, textbox

I am attempting to create an encryption machine where you type in a 5 digit number, it encrypts that number by changing the numbers then converting them into letters. The directions are as follows:

Add the necessary code to the “Encrypt” button to do the following:

a) Create a for loop to add 10 to the number entered on the first box and multiply the
  result by 3, add 20 to this result and then multiply it by 5, add 30 to this result and          then multiply it by 7, etc. Follow that pattern 5 times (5 iterations).

b) After the iterations have been completed, there will be a resulting number in
  memory, let's say 75432179

c) Now, this number needs to be turned into characters (letters) by matching each digit
to its corresponding letter of the alphabet based on the positions of the letters (0 will
be matched with the 10th letter of the alphabet). For our example: the resulting letters
will be: gedcbagi (g is the 7th letter of the alphabet, e is the 5th letter, d is the 4th
letter, etc.)

d) The last step of the encryption process is to further scramble the letters by using the
ancient Caesar's cipher: each letter replaced by another letter three positions to the
right. Therefore, the final result in our example would be: jhgfedjl (Notice that you
may also do steps c) and d) combined)

I have to display this whole thing in the form of a table with parameters:

Create a table with three columns and three rows

1. On the first column, just place descriptive information as illustrated in Figure 1 (Previous
   page)
2. Create two text boxes on the second column (set the size of the text boxes to 16)
3. Create one button on the third column. Label it “Encrypt”

I have the majority of the code done so far, but i cannot seem to get it to work. Here is my code so far:

```
<style type="text/css">
        body {background-color: black; color: lightgreen; font-family: helvetica; text-align: center}
        table {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto}
    </style>

    <body>
    <script type ="text/javascript">

        function encrypt(num) {
                var sum = 0, str, i, result, index;
                var chars = "abcdefghijklmnop";
                var charBase = "0".charCodeAt(0);
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                sum += (num * ((2 * i) + 3)) + ((i * 10) + 10);        
                }

                str = sum + "";
                result = "";
            for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                index = str.charCodeAt(i) - charBase + 3;
                result += chars.charAt(index);
            }
                return result;
        }
        document.getElementById("go").addEventListener("click", function() {
            var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value, 10);
            var out = encrypt(num);
            document.getElementById("encryptedValue").innerHTML = out;
        });


    </script>

        <h1>ATM</h1>
        <br/>
        <hr/>
        <br/>

        <table align="center" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Plaintext</b> (Plain information)</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="16" onchange=''/></td>
            <td><button id="go"> Encrypt </button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Ciphertext</b> (Encrypted information)</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="encryptValue" size="16" onchange=''/></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>.</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
```

Comment: Is this homework?  Are you going to write any of it yourself?

Comment: Are you the same user (different user id, but it appears to be the exact same text and problem) that wrote these two questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799558/setting-up-a-for-loop-for-an-encryption-scheme) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752881/for-loop-is-really-confusing-me) on the same topic?  If so, you should stick with one user id and only one user id, and since you appear to be using my code from one of those questions, can you please go accept that answer?

Comment: I really think you ought to write some code yourself.  The code in this answer so far is copied directly from my answer to a previous question.

Comment: jfriend00 I am a different user but I guess we are in the same class asking the same questions. I understand it is copied but that is because I seriously cannot find any help from my book or online, and never got any prior instruction for this. It would mean a great deal if you could help me out here.

Comment: @jfriend00 forgot to use the tag for my previous comment

Comment: Please ask one specific question.  "How do I do x?" and we will try to help you with that particular item.  Do your own internet research beforehand and show us what you've tried.  Stating that "you cannot get it to work" is not very descriptive and doesn't ask a specific question.  We aren't going to write your code for you and, since it's classwork, we really shouldn't.

Comment: @jfriend00  I merely added the whole entire code and directions to give who ever helps a better context in which to work. My specific question would be what function notion do I put in the new encrypted value text box to make the new and final ciphertext show up?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to respond to the one simpler question you put in your comment:

This line in the code you have:

```
 document.getElementById("encryptedValue").innerHTML = out;
```

puts the result of the encrypt operation into a non-form object on your page (such as a div or a span) that has `id="encryptedValue"`.  You can create a div or span in your HTML and give it that id and your code should put the result into that object on the page.

Or, change the `<input>` you have labeled Ciphertext to be a div.

Or, add the `id="encryptedValue"` to the Ciphertext `<input>` tag and change the above line of code to:

```
 document.getElementById("encryptedValue").value = out;
```

Comment: I tried that and the encyption still isnt showing up in the new textbox

Comment: document.getElementById("encryptedValue").value = out;
   });


  </script>

   <h1>ATM</h1>
   <br/>
   <hr/>
   <br/>

   <table align="center" border="1">
   <tr>
    <td><b>Plaintext</b> (Plain information)</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="16" onchange=''/></td>
    <td><button id="go"> Encrypt </button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><b>Ciphertext</b> (Encrypted information)</td>
    <td><input id="encryptedValue" size="16" onchange=''/></td>
    <td></td>

Comment: @user3496066 - as you can probably see, it is pointless to post multiple lines of code or HTML in a comment.  They simply aren't readable.  If you want people to understand what you just posted, then add it onto the end of your question and post a comment that says what you added and why.  Even better, put your code into a jsFiddle and share the link where everyone can see what is an isn't working.